# Where and how can I store data that is accessible from multiple Activities?

Tags: android, arrays, object, kotlin, android-activity

I am working on a `card game` (**not usual** 52 playing cards, but **own** cards with own values).
I have 2 Activities, `CardsToChoose` and `Deck`.

My Problem right now is, that I can't figure out how to display the cards I choose in `Deck`.
Where do I store the values of those cards, so that I can play with that Deck?

- Tried with Intent, but gets way too complicated
- Maybe it is possible with Objects, but I don't know how that works exactly...

Structure of my Cards (Not coded yet, because as said, I don't know where to put that code. Right know I only have a page with clickable ImageViews of my Cards ("CardsToChoose")):

```
Name: Card1
Value: score += 1 (If you play that card, the score goes up by 1)
```

I hope someone could explain how that works

Answer (score 0):

> This case is for scenario when you want only 1 card:

If the Cards are not the usual 52 but still let's say you defined `3` cards, `a`,`b` and `c`. From `Deck Activity` you want to pick a card and move to `CardsToChoose Activity` You can create a separate file outside the Activity called `Card.kt` and store the data for the cards over there. Now, inside the `Deck Activity`, you can refer to these cards with an `integer`, let's say `1` for `card a`, `2` for `card b` and `3` for `card c`. Now when user is in `Deck Activity` and picks a card and wants to move to `CardsToChoose Activity`, you can pass this `integer` based on the Card he picked using the `intent.putExtra("cardIndex", your_integer);`

Now in the `CardsToChoose Activity` you can get the index from Intent.

> For the case where you have multiple cardIndexes

For the case where you have multiple cardIndexes to be passed, you can either pass an `array` or use a `ViewModel` to share the data between activities. Here is how to pass an array of `Integer` Card Indices:

> let's say 1 and 2 are selected card indices

`int array[] = {1,2};`

```
Intent i = new Intent(DeckActivity.this, CardsToChooseActivity.class);
i.putExtra("numbers", array);
startActivity(i);
```

and then you can receive the array in CardsToChooseActivity using:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] arrayB = extras.getIntArray("numbers");
```